# jQuery mobile and PhoneGap using sessions to ensure user cant go "back" to or visit a page unless logged in

Tags: authentication, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am in the middle of making an app using a PHP web service to log users in/authenticate their credentials.

I am using localStorage (part of phonegaps local storage API) to ensure the user doesnt have to keep logging in when they open the app. This is done by storing the username and password on local storage and checking it when the app opens. If they feel the need to log out I have a simple logout button binded to a tap event which clears their local storage.

```
    $( '#logout' ).live( 'tap',function(event){

    window.localStorage.clear();
    $.mobile.changePage("#loginPage", {transition: "none"});


});
```

BUT... when logged out, they are still able to click the back button on the phone and get into the secure area, which doesnt make sense because the "welcome, (username)" part is all messed up etc...

Im wondering if there is a way to ensure that what ever page they open does some sort of check to make sure theyre logged in??

Comment: I have the same issue in Coldfusion. Trying to solve it by redirecting to the login page with rel="external" when the user logs out. This should more or less "dump" the app instance and create a new one. Also I'm having a server-side redirect on every page that checks for login status and if not set, I'm redirecting to the login page aswell. Not sure you can use this, but it's a start

Comment: Thanks! ill experiment with it. I did have an idea though... was going to have a jQuery function that runs on each page init, which would check to see if a username and/or password is present in localStorage. If not present then just mobile.changePage to loginpage. Would this work u think?

Comment: You beat me by 7 secs!!!

Comment: Lol yeah thanks though, you explained it clearer than I thought it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind into the `pagebeforeshow` event of the pages to check if the user is logged on - check if credentials are present in local storage.

If user is not logged on you can either call `preventDefault` to stop the `pageChange` or better redirect the user to a loggedOffPage by modifying the `toPage` passed into the handler.

Refer the `Page change events` section on [JQM Events page](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html).